# How to find longest sub-array whose elements (digits) can be rearranged to form a palindrome in c#?

Tags: c#

This is my code

```c#
using System;

public class Program
{

     private static string GetLongestPalindrome(string input)
    {
        int rightIndex = 0, leftIndex = 0;
        var x = "";
        string currentPalindrome = string.Empty;
        string longestPalindrome = string.Empty;
        for(int currentIndex = 1; currentIndex < input.Length - 1; currentIndex++)
        {
            leftIndex = currentIndex - 1;
            rightIndex = currentIndex + 1;
            while(leftIndex >= 0 && rightIndex < input.Length)
            {
                if(input[leftIndex] != input[rightIndex])
                {
                    break;
                }
                currentPalindrome = input.Substring(leftIndex, rightIndex - leftIndex + 1);
                if(currentPalindrome.Length > x.Length)
                    x = currentPalindrome;
                leftIndex--;
                rightIndex++;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetLongestPalindrome("12345354987"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input  = 12345354987,output = 345543.
```

Here the longest sub-array is 345354 which can be rearranged to form 345543 which is a palindrome.
In the above code I got palindrome number 45354. But the above input contains largest palindrome number is `345354` after rearrange `345543` using C#.

Comment: The largest potential palindrome is `3453549`, not `345354`. The palindrome is `3459543`.

Answer (score 3):

Baby steps...

Your method is doing too much, break it down into smaller problems you can handle. What do we need to solve?

1. Extract all possible subtrings from a given string.
2. Verify if a given string can be mutated into a palindrome shifting positions of individual characters.

Ok, lets do that:

Getting all substrings is relatively easy:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllSubSequences(
    this string s)
    => from start in Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
       from length in Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - start)
       select s.Substring(start, length);
```

Or if you prefer fluent syntax:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllSubSequences(string s)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                 .SelectMany(start => Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - start),
                             (start, length) => s.Substring(start, length));
```

Now we need a method that can tell us if a given string can be shifted into a palindrome. Hmmm... how can we do this easily? We could check all possible shifts but that seems pretty messy and wasteful.

Palindromes come in two flavours; even length palindromes `123321` and uneven length `123444321`. Do you see any pattern in these two we can leverage? It would seem that in the former case the total count of each character must be even. In the latter, the condition is almost the same, but there must also be one and only one character with an uneven total count.

Ok, lets implement this:

```
private static bool IsRearrangableIntoPalindrome(
    this IEnumerable<char> characters) 
    =>  characters.Count() % 2 == 0 ?
        //all even
        characters.GroupBy(c => c)
                  .All(g => g.Count() % 2 == 0):
        //one odd
        characters.GroupBy(c => c)
                  .Count(g => g.Count() % 2 != 0) == 1;
```

And now, we simply put everything together:

```
var str = "12345354987";
var largestPotentialPalindrome =
    str.GetAllSubSequences()
       .Where(s => s.IsRearrangableIntoPalindrome())
       .OrderBy(s => s.Length)
       .LastOrDefault();
```

And sure enough, the answer is `3453549` which is the largest substring that can be shifted into a palindrome: `3459543` (among others).

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Yeah, you are right, its pointless. Changed it to a method that simply returns all substrings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming late since a great answer has already been provided to this question, but since I started working on this yesterday and I just finished, I wanted to share my approach with the community anyway.

I decided to solve this problem without using `LINQ` and producing code as "traditional" as possible. The first problem was finding a way to detect a `potential palindrome`. As stated by @InBetween and by many other StackExchange users in other threads I googled for, the simplest way is:

- **Even Strings:** all the character occurrences must be even
- **Odd Strings:** all the character occurrences must be even except one

Here is my implementation:

```
private static Boolean IsPotentialPalindrome(String input)
{
    Dictionary<Char,Int32> occurrences = new Dictionary<Char,Int32>();
    Int32 inputLength = input.Length;

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < inputLength; ++i)
    {
        Char c = input[i];

        if (occurrences.ContainsKey(c))
            ++occurrences[c];
        else
            occurrences.Add(c, 1);
    }

    if ((inputLength % 2) == 0)
    {
        foreach (Int32 occurrence in occurrences.Values)
        {
            if ((occurrence % 2) != 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Boolean oddSpotted = false;

        foreach (Int32 occurrence in occurrences.Values)
        {
            if ((occurrence % 2) != 0)
            {
                if (oddSpotted)
                    return false;
                else
                    oddSpotted = true;
            }
        }

        if (!oddSpotted)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Once the hardest part was done, I created the main method to detect the longest potential palindromes (which includes the creation of all the possible `substrings` of the given input). Since one or more potential palindromes with the maximum length can be detected, I choose to return a `List`. Here is it:

```
private static List<String> GetLongestPotentialPalindromes(String input)  
{
    input = input.Trim().ToLowerInvariant();

    List<String> potentials = new List<String>();

    if (input.Length < 2)
        return potentials;

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)  
    {  
        String potential = String.Empty;

        for (Int32 j = i; j < input.Length; ++j)  
        {  
            potential += input[j];

            if ((potential.Length > 1) && !potentials.Contains(potential) && IsPotentialPalindrome(potential))
                potentials.Add(potential);
        }  
    }

    if (potentials.Count < 2)
        return potentials;

    Int32 maximumLength = 0;

    foreach (String potential in potentials)
    {
        Int32 potentialLength = potential.Length;

        if (potentialLength > maximumLength)
            maximumLength = potentialLength;
    }

    List<String> finalPotentials = new List<String>();

    foreach (String potential in potentials)
    {
        if (potential.Length == maximumLength)
            finalPotentials.Add(potential);
    }

    return finalPotentials;
}
```

A working demo of my implementation can be found [here](http://rextester.com/WJWC84087). Using your input, it finds out that the two longest potential palindromes are:

```
2345354
3453549
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it a bit more efficient. Some observations

- you can make palindrome from string iff at most one character is repeated odd number of times
- therefore you need only binary histogram for characters - if it is repeated even or odd number of times. You can use `HashSet` for this. Present item would mean it is repeated odd number of times.
- adding character to histogram is equivalent to deleting from it, odd changes to even and vice versa.
- `HashSet` histogram has one big advantage - you can test how many odd items you have in constant time.
- Histograms for overlapping substrings are simmilar. You can add/remove characters that differ in the substrings to get one histogram from another. You can use incremental changes to avoid building everything from cratch over and over again.
- You can start testing from longest substrings. When you find one, that can be palindrome, you do not have to test shorter substrings as you look for the longest only.
- do not allocate huge number of objects where not necessary
- If you have string of length `len` with 5 (different) characters that occur odd number of times, then you do not have to test its substrings longer than `len - 4`. Removing only 3 characters would leave at least 2 odd characters. This statement can be generalized.

The code is here, depending on the input, it can be several orders of magnitude faster than the basic brute force approach.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLongestPotentialPalindromes2(string input)
{
    HashSet<char> odds = new HashSet<char>();
    void AddToSet(char c)
    {
        if (!odds.Add(c)) { odds.Remove(c); }
    }

    for (int len = input.Length; len > 0;)
    {
        odds.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i)
        {
            AddToSet(input[i]);
        }
        int minOddCount = int.MaxValue;
        for (int start = 0; start <= input.Length - len; ++start)
        {
            AddToSet(input[start + len - 1]);
            int oddCount = odds.Count;
            if (oddCount <= 1) { yield return input.Substring(start, len); }
            minOddCount = Math.Min(minOddCount, oddCount);
            AddToSet(input[start]);
        }
        if (minOddCount <= 1) { yield break; }
        len -= minOddCount - 1;
    }
}
```